# Using rank order to calculate death rate data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table, aggregate, rank

I want to rank each hour value within each individual id. The hour values that equal each other will be the same rank. I attempted to do this with the row count function (.N) in data.table. I was hoping this would work but I cannot figure it out.

Here is a reproducible example, please let me know if you have any questions about my problem.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(hours=c(100, 72, 48, 98, 87, 75, 98, 75, 52, 48, 100, 98, 87, 35, 48, 75, 92, 100, 75, 48),
                 id=rep(1:4, each=5, 1))

dt <- dt[, list(.(hours <= hours), .N), list(hours, id)]
```

## Desired output

[image: counts of rank]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[Updated]:

A side goal of this question was to get the death rate over time from the different "id" groups. This was done with the following code, I also included a cool graph to show this relationship over time. The code was adapted from the answer provided by akrun using the frankv() function in the data.table package.

```
 library(ggplot2)

dt <- dt[,list(tot=.N, hours=hours), list(id)]
dt[, rank.total := frankv(hours, ties.method = 'max'), id]
dt[, death:= rank.total/tot, id]
dt[, alive:= 1-death, id]

ggplot(dt, aes(x=hours, y=alive, color=as.factor(id))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x="Hours", y="% Alive", title= "Death rate over time", color="Group")
```

[image: Death rate plot]

Comment: `dt[,rnk:=rank(hours,ties.method="min"),by="id"]` gives you the proper rank. Your desired output may be considered incorrect in the presence of ties, since in the case of id 4 hours 92 one would expect that with a rank of 3 that there would only be 2 values lower (there are 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `match`

```
library(data.table)
dt[, rank.total := match(hours, unique(hours)), id]
```

If we need to reverse rank, use `frank`

```
dt[, rank.total := frank(-hours, ties.method = 'dense'), id]
dt
#    hours id rank.total
# 1:   100  1          1
# 2:    72  1          4
# 3:    48  1          5
# 4:    98  1          2
# 5:    87  1          3
# 6:    75  2          2
# 7:    98  2          1
# 8:    75  2          2
# 9:    52  2          3
#10:    48  2          4
#11:   100  3          1
#12:    98  3          2
#13:    87  3          3
#14:    35  3          5
#15:    48  3          4
#16:    75  4          3
#17:    92  4          2
#18:   100  4          1
#19:    75  4          3
#20:    48  4          4
```

To change it usual order

```
dt[, rank.total := frank(hours, ties.method = 'dense'), id]
dt
#    hours id rank.total
# 1:   100  1          5
# 2:    72  1          2
# 3:    48  1          1
# 4:    98  1          4
# 5:    87  1          3
# 6:    75  2          3
# 7:    98  2          4
# 8:    75  2          3
# 9:    52  2          2
#10:    48  2          1
#11:   100  3          5
#12:    98  3          4
#13:    87  3          3
#14:    35  3          1
#15:    48  3          2
#16:    75  4          2
#17:    92  4          3
#18:   100  4          4
#19:    75  4          2
#20:    48  4          1
```

Or with `match`

```
dt[, rank.total := match(hours, rev(sort(unique(hours)))), id]
```

Comment: I asked the same question to Ronak Shah, but is there a way to reverse the order of ranks? Lowest value is the highest rank, and the highest value is the lowest rank?

Comment: The first solution does not seem to work with the data set. However, the frank and match solutions work well to rank the orders. The frank solution does not reverse the order, instead, it ranks them according to largest to smallest. I was wondering a way to do the opposite.

Comment: @ConnorMurray  In that case, `dt[, rank.total := frank(hours, ties.method = 'dense'), id]` removed the `-` (as I was not sure how you want it rankedd)

Answer (score 2):

You could convert `hours` to `factor` and then `integer` which would handle the ties properly automatically as per your desired output.

```
library(data.table)
dt[, rank.total := as.integer(factor(hours)), id]
dt

#    hours id rank.total
# 1:   100  1          5
# 2:    72  1          2
# 3:    48  1          1
# 4:    98  1          4
# 5:    87  1          3
# 6:    75  2          3
# 7:    98  2          4
# 8:    75  2          3
# 9:    52  2          2
#10:    48  2          1
#11:   100  3          5
#12:    98  3          4
#13:    87  3          3
#14:    35  3          1
#15:    48  3          2
#16:    75  4          2
#17:    92  4          3
#18:   100  4          4
#19:    75  4          2
#20:    48  4          1
```

---

You can also do the same in `dplyr` and base R

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%  group_by(id) %>% mutate(total.rank = as.integer(factor(hours)))
```

and

```
dt$total.rank <- with(dt, ave(hours, id, FUN = function(x) as.integer(factor(x))))
```

Comment: This is great, is there any way to reverse the order? Where min(value) == 1 and max(value) == min(rank)?

Comment: @ConnorMurray I guess you can just add `-` sign for `hours` like `dt[, rank.total := as.integer(factor(-hours)), id]`